# Android how to change fragments in for loop with thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I have an `activity class` .`oncreate` method of it, I `dynamically` take `imageview`s and set `draglisteners` to them.

And in `oncreate`, I open a `for loop`. In each loop, there are `imageviews` and when user drags on to correct imageview, it should go to other iteration , new images will be loaded.

But it doesnot work.

pseude code is like that:

```
oncreate(){

 for(){
    get images;
    put images to screen;
    if drag true, end this iteration and i++
      }//end of for
}//end of oncreate
```

it is not working. I use threads , handlers, postdelays but all of them did not work. They dont stop for iteration.

And i cant get if user dragged true because ondraglistener return true to somewhere else. Should i define some variable like `isDraggedTrue` to change inside ondraglistener to check in oncreate?

Comment: We can't just guess what's wrong. Post your code and tell us what you already tried, what you find when debbuging etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254250/android-change-layout-in-each-iterations

Comment: full activity is here: 

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/87ccd4147ae0d202244bb78f51844f29

Comment: If you expect me to read 300 lines of code, without a clear explanation of what's happening, you are wrong.

Comment: clear explanatiın is that i have  matching game activity. user matches the main image by dragging to correct one. there is a for loop inside oncreate. each iteration is a level of game. every level has different images and nmbers. so, if user drags correct,it should go other iteration but i cant do this. i used threads,handlers but it doesnot work.i used a int variable to take from ondragend if user dragged or not.

Comment: you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259518/android-how-to-understand-if-dragged-to-correct-place-in-main-thread-oncreate